# regex to split at dot|semicolon-space but ignore urls for example

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to parse and match a lot of legal text, splitting it all up into individual sentences.
I have the following regex which would work for just a few lines of easy text just fine:

```
[^\.\!\?\;\n]*[\.\!\?\;\n](\s+)
```

! and ? or pretty irrelvant here but . and ; as separators are quite common in the texts I'm trying to work with. The problem is that the above regex is just finding those delimiters followed by a space character.
The following text for example would not be properly matched:

> Member State law or pursuant to contract with a health professional
>   and subject to the conditions and safeguards referred to in paragraph
>   3; processing is necessary for reasons of public interest in the area
>   of public health, such as protecting against serious cross-border
>   threats to health or ensuring high standards comparison tool at
>   https://ec.europa.eu/ploteus/en/compare Adopted 7 comparable
>   procedures (e. g. certifications/audits), and registered as required
>   by the Member State.  of quality and safety of health care and of
>   medicinal products or medical devices, on the basis of Union or Member
>   State law, which provides for suitable and specific measures to
>   safeguard the rights and freedoms of the data subject, in particular
>   professional secrecy; processing is...

the following entire section:

> processing is necessary for reasons of public interest in the area of
>   public health, such as protecting against serious cross-border threats
>   to health or ensuring high standards comparison tool at
>   https://ec.europa.

would not be matched at all.

Any help in improving the above regex would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Please tag the programming language. If it happens to be `Python`, have a look at  [**The Natural Language Toolkit**](https://www.nltk.org/)

Comment: @Olaf For Go, we have https://github.com/jdkato/prose, it should do the job like a charm. Personally, I never used, but I am eager to. haha. Good luck!

Comment: @JamilloSantos Thanks Jamillo, that indeed seems to have solved my headaches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the name of what you want is a sentence tokenizer. For Go, I can recommend one library: [github.com/jdkato/prose](https://github.com/jdkato/prose), it should do the job like a charm.

Personally, I never used. Good luck!